# Why does decorator fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

I have problem with my decorator:

```
class ReviewDecorator < Draper:Decorator
  delegate_all

  def author
    @author = User.find_by(review.user_id)
    "#{@author.firstname} #{@author.lastname}"
  end
end
```

Every time I test this decorator, I receive this error:

> ReviewDecorator#author displays review author fullname
>        Failure/Error: expect(review.author).to eq 'John Doe'
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `firstname' for nil:NilClass
>        # ./app/decorators/review_decorator.rb:7:in`author'
>        # ./spec/decorators/review_decorator_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in '

Rspec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ReviewDecorator do

  let(:user) { build(:user, firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe') }
  let(:review) { described_class.new(build(:review, user: user)) }

  describe '#author' do
    it 'displays review author fullname' do
      expect(review.author).to eq 'John Doe'
    end
  end
end
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the spec also? Have you stubbed the an author or is there an author in the test db prior to calling this test?

Comment: I edited my main post and added rspec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your test file, the code should be like this.

```
class ReviewDecorator < Draper:Decorator
  delegate_all

  def author
    "#{user.firstname} #{user.lastname}"
  end
end
```